# Add Laravel Schedule in Controller Action

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduler

I have an web app that is supposed to scan any given site for metrics and send the report as an email. I fetch site url and email id from form and send it to controller action. Then in the action method, I want to run a system command in ubuntu to start the website scan and return the output to the method once done. I want to achieve the running of system command using laravel scheduler as using exec() command doesnt work as expected. If the command takes more time to execute then I get connection reset error. hence I wanted to schedule this task as cron job so that the execution can take its own time to complete and once completed, I can call another controller action to send the results to an email. Can someone help how to achieve this using laravel task scheduler.

Comment: You could run try by running Artisan commands like so: `Artisan::call('command:name', ['--option' => 'foo']);`